# Do I use a refresh token?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, authorization, refresh-token

I have an application that doesn't have user accounts so doesn't need a login. I'm currently authenticating using JWT via a `/get-token` endpoint in my api that's called as soon as the UI starts and returns a bearer token that's used for the calls for the calls moving forwards/

When that token expires, i'm a little confused at how to handle that. I was thinking using a refresh token but all the tutorials i've seen are passing the refresh token back to the UI, isn't that unsafe? I was always under the idea that the refresh token was internal and is only used on the server to refresh expired tokens.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh tokens carry the information necessary to get a new access token. In other words, whenever an access token is required to access a specific resource, a client may use a refresh token to get a new access token issued by the authentication server. Common use cases include getting new access tokens after old ones have expired, or getting access to a new resource for the first time. Refresh tokens can also expire but are rather long-lived. **Refresh tokens are usually subject to strict storage requirements to ensure they are not leaked**. They can also be blacklisted by the authorization server.

Comment: In simpler terms. If a token is leaked, then someone is able to use that token to access the page/resource. It is the responsibility of the person siting behind the computer to not let anyone copy the token.

Comment: I recommend that you store your JWT in cookies for web applications, because of the additional security they provide, and the simplicity of protecting against CSRF with modern web frameworks. HTML5 Web Storage is vulnerable to XSS, has a larger attack surface area, and can impact all application users on a successful attack.

Comment: hey thanks for that info, so I am passing the refresh token back to the UI? Which the UI will send to the server to generate a new token?

Comment: Yes, refresh token is used in Frontend. Exactly as you described it. You generate a new refresh token in server when your token/refresh token has expired. Frontend should do a request to server to get the new refresh token.

Comment: Just another quick question, my application won't have any users as i mentioned. You said `It is the responsibility of the person siting behind the computer to not let anyone copy the token`, if i'm sending my refresh and access token back to the frontend, what's stopping someone from just checking the network tab and taking both?

Comment: The solution is to not let anyone go to your network tab and take it. :) Maybe you can consider that as security whole, but it would be kinda difficult to do it. Needs social hacking. People could also go into your saved Chrome password if they are able to click around.